# Running a piece of code by creating a single thread speeds-up execution

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, simd, avx2

I am trying some benchmarks using Intel AVX2 and Posix threads. 
Let's suppose that I am trying to find the minimum value in a sample.
When I create a simple program I run the avx_min function.
When I create a program which inside creates a Posix thread, I have changed the implementation of avx_min to avx_min_thread like it is shown below, but actual implementation remains the same. This function can be used for more than one threads and it does not need a synchronization, as threads do not "conflict" (tid = 0,1, 2, etc.).

When I compile both implementations without specifying any optimization flag, they give me both the same time result. One the other size, when I compile them using the -O3 flag they result in different execution times and I can not figure out why this happens.

P.S: I compile them using:

- case 1 (without creating a thread): g++ -mavx2 -O3 -o avxMinO3 avxMinO3.cpp
- case 2 (creating a posix thread inside): g++ -mavx2 avxMinO3_t.cpp -lpthread -O3 -o avxMinO3_t

P.S 2:

- 1st case execution time: 0.34 sec
- 2nd case execution time: 0.049 sec

```
Case 1:

double initialize_input(int32_t** relation, int32_t value_bound, int32_t input_size){

  clock_t t;
  srand(time(NULL));
  t = clock();
  for(int32_t i = 0 ; i < input_size ; i++){
    (*relation)[i] = rand() % value_bound;
  }
  t = clock() - t;
  return ((double) t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}


int* avx_min(int32_t** relation, int32_t rel_size, double* function_time){

  clock_t tic, tac;
  __m256i input_buffer;
  int32_t* rel = (*relation);
  __m256i min = _mm256_set_epi32(INT32_MAX, INT32_MAX, INT32_MAX, INT32_MAX, INT32_MAX, INT32_MAX, INT32_MAX, INT32_MAX);
  tic = clock();
  for(int i = 0 ; i < rel_size ; i += 8){
    input_buffer = _mm256_stream_load_si256((__m256i*)&rel[i]);
    min = _mm256_min_epi32(min, input_buffer);
  }
  tac = clock();
  double time_diff = (double)(tac - tic);
  (*function_time) = time_diff / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  int* temp = (int*)&min;
  return temp;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  int32_t* relation;
  double* function_time;
  int32_t input_size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
  int32_t value_bound = 1000;

  int alloc_time = initialize_input(&relation, value_bound, input_size);
  int* res = avx_min(&relation, input_size, function_time);
  return 0;
}
```

Case 2:

```
template<typename T>
struct thread_input {
  T* relation;
  T rel_size;
  double function_time;
  short numberOfThreads;
  short tid;
};


template<typename T, typename S, typename I, typename RELTYPE>
T** createAndInitInputPtr(S numberOfThreads, I rel_size, S value_bound, RELTYPE** relation ){
  T **result = new T*[numberOfThreads];

  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
    result[i] = new T;
    result[i]->rel_size = rel_size;
    result[i]->relation = (*relation);
    result[i]->numberOfThreads = numberOfThreads;
    result[i]->tid = i;
  }
  return result;
}


void* avx_min_t(void* input){

    clock_t tic, tac;
    struct thread_input<int32_t> *input_ptr;
    input_ptr = (struct thread_input<int32_t>*) input;

    int32_t* relation = input_ptr->relation;
    int32_t rel_size = input_ptr->rel_size;
    int32_t start = input_ptr->tid * 8;
    int32_t offset = input_ptr->numberOfThreads * 8;

    __m256i input_buffer;
    __m256i min = _mm256_set_epi32(INT32_MAX, INT32_MAX, INT32_MAX, INT32_MAX, INT32_MAX, INT32_MAX, INT32_MAX, INT32_MAX);
    tic = clock();
    for(int i = start ; i < rel_size ; i += offset){
      input_buffer = _mm256_stream_load_si256((__m256i*)&relation[i]);
      min = _mm256_min_epi32(min, input_buffer);
    }
    tac = clock();
    double time_diff = (double)(tac-tic);
    time_diff = time_diff / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    input_ptr->function_time = time_diff;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

  int rel_size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
  short numberOfThreads = 1;
  short value_bound = 1000;

  pthread_t* threads = new pthread_t[numberOfThreads];

  short flag = 1; // flag to check proper aligned memory allocations

  int32_t* relation;
  double alloc_time = 0.0;
  flag = posix_memalign((void**)&relation, 32, rel_size * sizeof(int32_t));
  if(flag) {
    std::cout << "Memory allocation problem. Exiting..." << std::endl;
    exit(1);
  }
  alloc_time += initialize_input(&relation, value_bound, rel_size);


  struct thread_input<int32_t> **input_ptr = createAndInitInputPtr<struct thread_input<int32_t>, short, int, int32_t>(numberOfThreads, rel_size, value_bound, &relation);

  clock_t tic = clock();

  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
    pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, avx_min_t,(void*) input_ptr[i]);
  }


  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
    pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
  }
  tic = clock()-tic;
  double time = tic / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  std::cout << time << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: your test duration is way to short to conclude anything, you should try runs lasting at _least_ 30 secondes

Comment: There's probably some bookkeeping done by the posix library - some static variables being initialized. If you want a better answer then provide [mcve].

Comment: @OznOg The size of input is almost 4GB (2^30 integers), I do not think that the test duration is the problem. I run it multiple times and it continues providing these time results.

Comment: Are you running both cases over the same uninitialized buffer in the same process?  So the first one has to page-fault in every page.  But the 2nd one can just zip through with only maybe some TLB misses.  If the buffer is uninitialized, then all its pages might be mapped to the same physical zero page.  Also, AVX2 can have a "warm-up" period for 256-bit vectors.  But that doesn't last long , like 14 microseconds in Agner Fog's testing of Skylake.  (https://www.agner.org/optimize/blog/read.php?i=415).  Probably some fixed number of core clock cycles.

Comment: `_mm256_stream_load_si256` on normal write-back memory is useless; it's just a slow `_mm256_load_si256`.

Comment: @OznOg: I think that nearly confirms my guess that the fast run is fast because it's 2nd, not because of threads.  And that the buffer is uninitialized so all the pages are mapped to the same physical zero-page, so it gets L1d cache hits and just the next-page prefetcher runs.  Or else the caller is passing a value greater than 1 for `input_ptr->numberOfThreads` and that thread version is doing way less work.  CPU performance counters would be one way to confirm that the number of instructions executed is about the same, although variable stride might defeat some optimizations.

Comment: And of course having the threads *stride* through memory is really horrible for cache and TLB compared to breaking it up into `numberOfThreads` contiguous chunks.  (If you were going to run more than 1 thread).  L1d and L2 cache are per-core private, and so are TLBs.  This makes every thread touch every page, and every cache line is touched by 2 threads so they both have to fetch it from L3.  So you'll have `n` times more TLB misses than necessary, and at least twice the L3 bandwidth consumption.  (The L2 spatial prefetcher tries to complete aligned pairs of cache lines if bandwidth allows.)

Comment: Mr @OznOg I am here to ask in order to learn and nothing more.

Comment: Mr @PeterCordes the two executions are independent from each other. I consider in splitting for individual chunks per thread, after finding what is going wrong with this case.

Comment: Mr @Quimby I attached some sample code. Thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: @PeterCordes For thread with id = 0 start will be 0, for thread with id = 1 start will be 8. Let's forget the matter that there is one global input rather than individual chunks. I will fix it.

Answer (score 3):

**`void* avx_min_t(void* input)` doesn't do anything with `min` so the SIMD work loading from the array optimizes away.**

Its inner loop compiles to this with `gcc -O3 -march=haswell`, and clang is basically the same.

```
.L3:
        add     ebx, r12d
        cmp     r13d, ebx
        jg      .L3
```

So it's literally just an empty loop in asm, taking 0.04 seconds to increment a pointer by `4GB / 32 bytes` times.

```
for(int i = start ; i < rel_size ; i += offset){
}
```

I think you meant to return something, because the function is declared `void*` and has undefined behaviour from falling off the end of a non-void function.  **GCC and clang warn about this by default without even needing `-Wall`**.  https://godbolt.org/z/Z1GWpU

```
<source>: In function 'void* avx_min_t(void*)':
<source>:66:1: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
   66 | }
      | ^
```

**Always check your compiler warnings, especially when your code behaves strangely.**  Enable `-Wall` and fix any warnings, too.

Comment: Thank you mister. I missed this bug. Thanks for mentioning it. I will change the implementation also for individual chunks per thread.

Comment: @P.L: if this answer solves your problem, please mark your question solved by clicking the checkbox under the vote arrows.